# Create bootstrap carousel with captions instead of dots

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Standard bootstrap carousel can contains dots to change slides (example on [bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)).

However, I recently read [Why Users Aren't Clicking Your Home Page Carousel](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-users-arent-clicking-your-home-page-carousel) which proposed using captions instead of dots like below:

[image: example]

Is this option possible in bootstrap? If so, how can I do so?

Comment: To answer your question, yes it is *possible*, but you'll have to write some code to do it.  What have you tried?

Comment: @KyleMit the question should be: were should I make changes to have such effect. I didn't write any code because I don't know where should I start. I don't want to change bootstrap.js

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can doing this by just overriding the styles on the `carousel-indicators` list items.

#### Here's a typical indicators section:

```html
<ul class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">One</li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">Two</li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">Three</li>
</ul>
```

#### You'll want to override some of the default Bootstrap styles:

Convert the display from dots to rectangles by adding a `width` and `height` and removing the `border-radius`:

[image: demo 1]

Then get the text back by removing the negative `text-indent` added by Bootstrap:

[image: demo 2]

Finally, add your own `background` and `border` and style however else you like.
The full styling should look like this:

```css
.carousel-indicators > li,
.carousel-indicators > li.active{
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    background: lightgrey;
    text-indent: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators > li.active {
    background: white;
}
```

## [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kQ5WC/)

[image: screenshot]

---

You could even wrap the entire bit of CSS inside of a media query so that when screen size became limited, you defaulted back to the dots instead of awkwardly stacking the list items:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
    /* Wrap CSS Here */
}
```

#### [Responsive Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kQ5WC/3/show/light/)

Comment: that was exactly the start point which I needed. It is a really cool trick with div's

Comment: 3 hours of fight are over now thanks to your answer! Thank you.